# TypeError: undefined is not a function when clone old node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to run a node app that I've cloned from
https://github.com/jensoleg/mongoose-timeseries

So I just cloned it and `npm install` and dependencies but when I ran an example file it gives this error! I've looked at the core code but I don't know what is the problem exactly.

```
mti.init('test', {interval: 1}); //second: Boolean, minute: Boolean
^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kanin/Desktop/test/test.js:7:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: It's saying `mti` is undefined.  Did you make any changes to the project?  It's expecting there to be a few files in the directory you've called `test`.  Do you see the `package.json` and `index.js` in that directory?

Comment: @Brennan actually it's say that there is no `init`.

Comment: @jcubic, my mistake, you are indeed correct.  I was looking at the arrow underneath that line, instead of the message.

Comment: I've read the core code it has an init function but don't know why it can't work?

Comment: @KaninPeanviriyakulkit, Are you certain that the `test` directory contains the `package.json` and `index.js`?  That's where `mti` is being required from if you're using the [example.js](https://github.com/jensoleg/mongoose-timeseries/blob/master/example/example.js) file from the repo.

Comment: @Brennan I used example.js at first it got the same error.

Comment: @KaninPeanviriyakulkit, you are correct.  I'm not convinced this library is ready for use.  The example is most certainly not using the library as it was intended.